# Foreground service android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I didn't find any documentation about that. Is it possible to create a foreground service on android wear? Usually the foreground state is related with an ongoing notification but it's not possible on wear so I'm a bit confused. Is there anyone has a foreground service on wear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation:

"The system enforces a timeout period. If you are displaying an activity and user's don't interact with it, the device sleeps. When it wakes back up, the Wear home screen is displayed instead of your activity. If you need to show something persistent, create a notification in the context stream instead."

So, i believe it's possible to have a persistent UI (may be not an ongoing foreground notification but a card or a stack instead).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Once you are able to achieve persistent UI, then you can use Intents like you typically use in handheld apps to trigger some action.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html. I am learning on the fly as well here. Developing for wearables is new to me too :)